# Definition of Critical Part in type certification process

Tags: aircraft-design, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, aircraft-certification

first time here :)

I'm part of the team at Flytrex (flytrex.com) and we're working with the Aircraft Certification Office to certify one of the first UAS systems (drones) under new initiative to certify drones for commercial use.
We are currently at the stage that we need to define our system critical parts.

From what I understand, a Critical Part is defined as a single point of failure that will lead to a crash of the aircraft.

Since every component in our system includes redundancies, is it reasonable to claim that we don't have any Critical Part?

Some examples:

- Single motor loss - the aircraft uses 6 motors and can sustain a single motor loss.
- Multiple motor loss - an independent parachute system is deployed, taking the aircraft to the ground safely.
- Flight controller loss - again, parachute will deploy.
- Parachute system failure - the flight controller will bring the aircraft back to safe landing (abort mission).

I think we need a clearer understanding what is considered a critical part, and then try to define the right parts in our system.

Many thanks!

Comment: Hello Amit Regev, interesting question! Welcome to Aviation.stackexchange.com

Comment: Electrical failure?

Comment: @JuanJimenez the parachute system is independent and monitors power outage, so the parachute will deploy in such case.

Comment: How does it monitor power outage? Is there a mechanical failsafe? What if the failsafe fails? Assume Murphy is watching and will throw everything at you. :)

Comment: You should check in with the certification office regarding the critical part definition, as the wording is important. In general, I would use a definition that designates every part whose failure in service could (not will) cause a catastrophic failure of the aircraft. This includes multiple failures and the degradation of the margins of safety of other critical parts.

Comment: Also, what @JuanJimenez said. How reliable is your power monitoring system? What are the effects of a false positive? What about your structure? Surely that is critical by any definition.